# Ошибка с markup клавиатурой aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram

Вот мой код:

```
import logging
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters.command import Command, CommandStart
from config_reader import config
from aiogram.exceptions import TelegramBadRequest
from aiogram import F
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import locale

exchange = requests.get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js').json()
USD = exchange['Valute']['USD']['Value']

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")

now = datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%A, %d %B")
time = now.strftime("%I:%M") 

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=config.bot_token.get_secret_value())
dp = Dispatcher() 

city_id = тут был айди
appid = "тут был мой токен"
try:
    res = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
                params={'id': city_id, 'units': 'metric', 'lang': 'ru', 'APPID': appid})
    data = res.json()
    temp = data['main']['temp']
    desc = data['weather'][0]['description']
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception (weather):", e)
    pass    

async def change_volume(volume):
    devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    interface = devices.Activate(
        IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))

    volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(volume, None)

    current_volume = volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar() 
    

async def on_startup():
    main_keyboard = [
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text="️Медиа"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="⚙️ПК"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="Информация"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="⚠️Админ")
        ],
    ]
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=main_keyboard,
        resize_keyboard=True
    )
    await bot.send_message(1085271555, f"️Приветствую Вас, сэр.\n\nСегодня {date}.\n⏳Время: {time}\nДоллар: {USD} RUB\n\n️В {desc} {temp}°C", reply_markup=keyboard)
    
    
@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def start(bot: Bot):
    main_keyboard = [
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text="️Медиа"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="⚙️ПК"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="Информация"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="⚠️Админ")
        ],
    ]
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=main_keyboard,
        resize_keyboard=True
    )
    await bot.send_message(1085271555, f"️Приветствую Вас, сэр.\n\nСегодня {date}.\n⏳Время: {time}\nДоллар: {USD} RUB\n\n️В{desc} {temp}°C", reply_markup=keyboard)
    

@dp.message(F.text.lower() == "Медиа")
async def media(message: types.Message):
    main_media_keyboard = [
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text=""),
            types.KeyboardButton(text=""),
            types.KeyboardButton(text=""),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="Звук"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="Меню")
        ],
    ]
    media_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=main_media_keyboard,
        resize_keyboard=True
    )
    await message.reply("Медиа", reply_markup=media_keyboard)
    
    
@dp.message(Command("clear"))
async def cmd_clear(message: types.Message, bot: Bot) -> None:
    try:
        for i in range(message.message_id, 0, -1):
            await bot.delete_message(1085271555, i)
    except TelegramBadRequest as ex:
        if ex.message == "Bad Request: message to delete not found":
            print("Все сообщения удалены")
    await on_startup()
    

async def main():
    await on_startup()
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

После нажатия на markup кнопку ️Медиа, ничего не происходит, пишет что не является хендлером.

```
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=443962299 is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=6542520380
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == "Медиа")
```

Тут ты для чего-то приводишь исходное сообщение к нижнем регистру, а потом сравниваешь со словом Медиа, в котором есть заглавная буква. Соответственно, хендлер и не срабатывает, потому что строки не равны

Убери `lower()` и хендлер сработает:

```
@router.message(F.text == "️Медиа")
async def media(message: types.Message):
    main_media_keyboard = [
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text=""),
            types.KeyboardButton(text=""),
            types.KeyboardButton(text=""),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="Звук"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="Меню")
        ],
    ]
    media_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=main_media_keyboard,
        resize_keyboard=True
    )
    await message.reply("Медиа", reply_markup=media_keyboard)
```